# Can someone explain me the output ? (C++11)

Tags: c++11

```
int main(){ 
    auto func1 = [](int y) { 
         cout << y << " "; 
    }; 
    auto func2 = [](int y) {
         cout << y * y << " "; 
    }; 
    cout << "func1 is : " << typeid(func1).name() << endl; 
    cout << "func2 is : " << typeid(func2).name() << endl;  
    cout << "main is : " << typeid(main).name() << endl; 
}
```

OSX output:

func1 is : Z4mainE3$_0

func2 is : Z4mainE3$_1

main is : FivE

Can someone explain the output ??

Thanks, I am just exploring some c++11 features.

Comment: The name mangling is not part of the language standard, so it's not a "language feature" per se. What exactly do you want explained?

Comment: Interesting. In g++ 4.8.4 the output is func1 is : Z4mainEUliE_
func2 is : Z4mainEUliE0_
main is : FivE

Comment: Your program has UB, since "the function `main` shall not be used within a program". So you're not allowed to pass it to `typeid` :-)

Comment: [Itanium ABI name mangling rules](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling). E.g. `F...E` delimits a function type, and `iv` says "return type `int`, parameter types `void`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining FivE, that was interesting,

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is the [name mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of each of these symbols.  This is what `typeid.name()` for your compiler implementation returns. There is no requirement that the mangled name precisely relates directly to your code. Using the mangled symbol names already present in the object files for linking is a convenient implementation choice.

You can unmangle names using the `c++filt` tool:
Thus:

```
$ c++filt _FivE
```

yields

```
int ()
```

In other words, a function returning an int.  Remember that what you are asking for here is the *type* of the function and not its *name*.

If you were to apply this to a class

```
class foo
{
};

cout << "foo is : " << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
```

You will find output is `3foo` and the unmanged name `foo`.

The two lambdas don't unmangle.  This is because they are anonymous functions, so don't need an external name.

Furthermore, compiler generates a functor class for each lambda. The first of which would look like

```
struct Z4mainE3
{
    void operator()(int y)
    {
        cout << y << " ";
    }
}
```

This means that each one is a distinct type. The name is synthetic, and generated by the compiler such that is won't collide with anything else.

The `typeid` operator will operate on the functor struct and not the apparent return and argument type of the lambda itself, hence the two of them are a different type despite apparently being functions having the same signature.

The long-standing advice about `typeid().name()` operator is that it is not portable; you [should not rely on the values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returned.

Comment: glad to know c++filt, it is interesting that typeid().name does mangling symbols. that is why I get 'd' for typeid(double).name(); and 'f' for typeid(float).name();  very interesting. And sorry I cannot vote your answer publicly as I do not have enough reputation points..

Comment: You shouldn't say that `typeid().name()` is not portable. It is portable, but the name returned is system dependent. However you can use it e.g. with [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index). One other small suggestion: on UNIX/Linux you can also pipe the output of the program through `c++filt`, like `./a.out | c++filt`.

Comment: thank you, vsoftco, c++ is pretty complex. I learnt a lot : )